# Can we set content priority of component in react-native?

Tags: ios, flexbox, react-native

In AutoLayout, we can arrange multiple views based on constraints, for example, if I have a UILabel and a UIImageView positioned in single line, I can do like this:

```
UILable *label = [UILabel new];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[self.view addSubview:label];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[label mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.bottom.top.equalTo(self.view);
    make.right.equalTo(imageView.mas_left);
}];

[imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.right.bottom.top.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

Now, if I want to keep content of `label` not be compressed, in traditional AutoLayout way is to set `label`'s contentCompressionResistancePriority higher, then layout system will keep content of `label` not to be compressed, if the rest space on horizon axis is not enough, the width of `imageView` will be compressed. All of this based on `content size`, or `intrinsicContentSize` precisely .

Go ahead more, I'm going to re-implement a native custom view into JS which use intrinsicContentSize property to calculate whether it should show its content completely. The target of the custom view is for showing multiple tags side by side horizontally, in my native implementation, I will check the bounds of each subview in `layoutSubviews` method whether beyond its super view:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat width = 0;    
    bool update = NO;

    for(UIView * subview in self.subviews) {
        if(subview.frame.origin.x + subview.width > self.width) {
            subview.hidden = YES;
            update = YES;
        } else {
            subview.hidden = NO;
            width = subview.origin.x + subview.width;
        }
    }

    if(update) {
        self.fitSize = CGSizeMake(width, self.fitSize.height);
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];    //in intrinsicContentSize method, return self.fitSize
    }
}
```

Now the AutoLayout knows what really size the view is, it will base on the true size of it for layout. I also want to use react native to achieve this, but I found that I can't set the relationship between two components like I use constraint-based AutoLayout nor override `intrinsicContentSize` method to calculate real size the view I want it be, is there any solution for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

React Native uses [the CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to layout it's views. This is very similar to `UIStackView`; In other words, all the things you're asking for in your question is really relevant for laying out React Native views!

The best way to describe this is to compare it with iOS 9's `UIStackView`. If you're not familiar with that, I strongly urge you to [check out this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views) as once you're familiar with `UIStackView` it'll be a piece of cake to bridge over that knowledge to `Flexbox`.

In React Native, you use the a `StyleSheet` to define the the layouts of your view. Consider the following style:

```
const styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "vertical",
    flex: 1,
  }
})
```

This `container` style is essentially defining a `UIStackView` with items aligned vertically.

[image: StackView Attributes Screenshot]

The presence of a `flex` value signifies that the elements in the container will refer to their own flex values to determine the **content hugging priority**.

This is *key*. Like you've mentioned, React Native's layout can be fully manipulated by manipulating how it interprets each view's intrinsic content size.

Consider the following layout:

[image: storyboard layout example]

Let's focus on the bottom tab bar. Assume the tab bar itself has the style of the aforementioned `container` style (with `flexDirection: "horizontal"`).

To achieve this layout in React Native, you need to specify a flex value for all the child elements. The higher the `flex` value, the **less** content hugging priority it has when compared to it's siblings. To put it in another way, the higher the `flex` value of 1 sibling enforces a higher content hugging priority on all other siblings with a lower `flex` value.

As such, the layout StyleSheet might look like this:

```
const styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  //flex box containing the child elements
  container: {
    flexDirection: "horizontal",
    flex: 1
  },

  //the three child elements nested inside the container
  plusButton: {
    flex: 1
  },
  chooseSourcePlaylistButton: {
    flex: 2
  },
  settingsButton: {
    flex: 1
  },
})
```

Because you want the middle view to expand and push the other elements to the edge, you want it to **dominate** the flex box by giving it a bigger `flex` value.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! I suddenly realized flex value in flexbox is equal to so call content priority I have mentioned:) But as another question, I didn't have any idea yet. If I expect `continuous` width compression, I can solve the problem by simply set flex value bigger, but my expectation is `discrete` compression, which means if my custom view's size is big enough for showing two tags completely, then show two, if its size can only show 1.5 tag(we presume that), it will show one tag and hide another one, then set intrinsicContentSize to one tag size in  `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: All of my calculation in native code is based on the `frame`, like the code showing in my question, but in flexbox layout system, I can't do that kind of calculation, or maybe I just have not find the right way to do that... This is my update about your answer, hope that you are clear about what I'm talking about, thanks again.